# How to work with only the first "X" siblings from an xml

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, jmeter

I've been running a series of webservice tests in JMeter, and what I've been doing is modifying my results report to include the total sum of the average response times returned by each test. But what I also need to do is take the sum of the averages times up until a certain test. Is there a way I could modify the XSLT to sum the test averages for every test except test "X" and those after it? e.g. lb="getSubscribers"?

[Here is what the results report typically looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2ZEB.png) Essentially I want to sum the contents of the Average Time column from the "http" test, to the "AlarmMgmtWSDL" test.

Here is my XML from JMeter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="../style/jmeter-results-detail-report_21.xsl"?>
<testResults version="1.2">
<httpSample t="78" lt="78" ts="1338826079163" s="true" lb="html" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="vuserver 1-1" dt="text" by="4418" ng="1" na="1"/>
<httpSample t="31" lt="31" ts="1338826079241" s="true" lb="userRoleRetriever" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="vuserver 1-1" dt="text" by="758" ng="1" na="1"/>
<httpSample t="32" lt="32" ts="1338826079272" s="true" lb="UserActivityWSDL" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="vuserver 1-1" dt="text" by="2398" ng="1" na="1"/>
<httpSample t="156" lt="125" ts="1338826079304" s="true" lb="SubscriberMgmtWSDL" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="vuserver 1-1" dt="text" by="56434" ng="1" na="1"/>
<httpSample t="31" lt="16" ts="1338826079460" s="true" lb="NetworkMgmtWSDL" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="vuserver 1-1" dt="text" by="33020" ng="1" na="1"/>
<httpSample t="15" lt="15" ts="1338826079507" s="true" lb="AlarmMgmtWSDL" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="vuserver 1-1" dt="text" by="11594" ng="1" na="1"/>
<httpSample t="141" lt="141" ts="1338826079538" s="true" lb="getSubscribers" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="vuserver 1-1" dt="text" by="397" ng="1" na="1"/>
<httpSample t="265" lt="234" ts="1338826079679" s="true" lb="getMpegResultsById" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="vuserver 1-1" dt="text" by="832927" ng="1" na="1"/>
<httpSample t="15" lt="15" ts="1338826079976" s="true" lb="getOverallSummary" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="vuserver 1-1" dt="text" by="402" ng="1" na="1"/>
<httpSample t="0" lt="0" ts="1338826082663" s="true" lb="html" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="vuserver 1-2" dt="text" by="4418" ng="1" na="1"/>
<httpSample t="16" lt="16" ts="1338826082663" s="true" lb="userRoleRetriever" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="vuserver 1-2" dt="text" by="758" ng="1" na="1"/>
<httpSample t="15" lt="0" ts="1338826082679" s="true" lb="UserActivityWSDL" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="vuserver 1-2" dt="text" by="2398" ng="1" na="1"/>
<httpSample t="32" lt="0" ts="1338826082694" s="true" lb="SubscriberMgmtWSDL" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="vuserver 1-2" dt="text" by="56434" ng="1" na="1"/>
<httpSample t="31" lt="15" ts="1338826082726" s="true" lb="NetworkMgmtWSDL" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="vuserver 1-2" dt="text" by="33020" ng="1" na="1"/>
<httpSample t="16" lt="16" ts="1338826082757" s="true" lb="AlarmMgmtWSDL" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="vuserver 1-2" dt="text" by="11594" ng="1" na="1"/>
<httpSample t="250" lt="250" ts="1338826082788" s="true" lb="getSubscribers" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="vuserver 1-2" dt="text" by="10536" ng="1" na="1"/>
<httpSample t="15454" lt="15392" ts="1338826083038" s="true" lb="getMpegResultsById" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="vuserver 1-2" dt="text" by="2023426" ng="1" na="1"/>
<httpSample t="15" lt="15" ts="1338826098555" s="true" lb="getOverallSummary" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="vuserver 1-2" dt="text" by="402" ng="1" na="1"/>

</testResults>
```

I need to work with the first X number of test results from that XML, exclude the rest, and at the same time keep the X number of test results when they occur on he second iteration so I can take the averages.

This is an excerpt from my xslt that finds the total sum of the test averages:

```
<xsl:variable name="totalAverageTime">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="httpSample" group-by="@lb">
        <xsl:variable name="count" select="count(current-group())" />
        <xsl:variable name="totalTime" select="sum(current-group()/@t)" />
        <average avg="{$totalTime div $count}" />
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:variable>

<tr>  
  <td>
    <xsl:call-template name="display-time">
        <xsl:with-param name="value" select="sum($totalAverageTime/average/@avg)" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Any ideas on how to work with these certain tests? Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can do this. Firstly you could add an **xsl:if** statement within the **xsl:for-each-group** so that only the first 7 grouped elements are output. In other words, it will consider all test results when doing the grouping, but only output the first 7 distinct ones.

```
<xsl:variable name="totalAverageTime">   
    <xsl:for-each-group select="httpSample" group-by="@lb">  
        <xsl:if test="position() &lt;= 7"> 
           <xsl:variable name="count" select="count(current-group())" />   
           <xsl:variable name="totalTime" select="sum(current-group()/@t)" />   
           <average avg="{$totalTime div $count}" /> 
       </xsl:if>  
    </xsl:for-each-group>   
</xsl:variable>
```

Alternatively, you could still build your **$totalAverageTime** with all test results, but just restrict yourself to looking at the first seven when it comes to outputing them.

```
<xsl:call-template name="display-time">    
    <xsl:with-param name="value" select="sum($totalAverageTime/average[position() &lt;= 7]/@avg)" />    
</xsl:call-template>
```

The latter method may be more flexible, as you would still have the full results to play with should you need them.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Decided to go with the second option as it allowed me to use the averages from totalAverageTime as a basis, and put the selected sum and total sum in my report table with minimal code change. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

please make use of of Xpath 2.0 in your XSLT document.

using an axe like "`child`" and the `position()` 'snode test you got your sibling subset:

```
/testResults/child::httpSample[position() lt  5]
```

gives your the first siblings which position on the set is smaller than 5: you'll got your first 4 siblings.

Generally  you get

```
/testResults/child::httpSample[position() lt  (X+1)]
```

were X is of the number of the first siblings your wish to choose from.

because `'AlarmMgmtWSDL'` is the `lb` attribute of the 6th element, you got

```
/testResults/child::httpSample[position() lt  7]
```

just change your variable '`totalAverageTime`' like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="totalAverageTime">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="httpSample[position() lt 7]" group-by="@lb">
        <xsl:variable name="count" select="count(current-group())"/>
        <xsl:variable name="totalTime" select="sum(current-group()/@t)"/>
        <average avg="{$totalTime div $count}"/>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:variable>
```